# WPF programs runs in Visual Studio 2010 but not when clicked on exe

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, exe

I've made a WPF application that runs perfectly inside Visual Studio 2010.
When I built it (debug or release mode) and try to run the app, I've got an error,
the form doesn't start.

any ideas?

thanks

Filip

Comment: Can you post the error message?. That will give a hint.

Comment: Error may possibly also be found in the Event viewer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have reference to the PresentationFramework.Aero try changing reference property "Copy Local" to true. It worked for me,

Answer (score 0):

I have had a problem similar to this, the main problem turned out to be related to reflection. Usually when this happens it is because the code gets optimized more than when the debugger is attached.

Comment: I had a reference to the Presentation Aero dll, in VS there is no problem, but when you run the app outside VS, it crashed